# AngularJS Ng-repeat <div> vs <ul> performance

Tags: html, angularjs, performance

basically I want to know if there is any performance difference using ul instead of div when I'm using ng-repeat

Comment: I feel like the two are quite incomparable. I can't imagine any performance hits would come from Angular, if there's anything it would be from the browser's rendering time, and probably not count for anything. But realistically, I'm not sure when you have a choice between the two. They're different elements that serve very different purposes, so I'm confused about the use-case here.

Comment: They're both "just" elements; ngRepeat doesn't (and shouldn't) know anything about the element that's being repeated, so I dont think you'll experience any performance difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a look at angular source code, but $compile only apply on $element, so obviously angular does not really care about your HTML tag.

Here is the code you are looking for : 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L323

As you can see, no specific use of $element in this code. The question is now more oriented on browser behaviors, which is a little bit more complexe questions complexe.

Just use the one which feel more adapted for your content. Have fun.

Comment: Thanks, That was what I was wondering, then it makes no sense to change all my code, my problems must be in another part of the code.